# Issues when user input data in sql command

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  a batch files which when i run calls a SQL file. This SQL file prompts user to input data which I store in MYPeriod( this accepts date as input ).the output of SQL file is a CSV file.
Here is my code for SQL file:

```
PROMPT Enter a period
ACCEPT MYPeriod PROMPT 'Period: '

SET LINESIZE 500 FEEDBACK OFF TRIMSPOOL ON TERMOUT OFF HEAD OFF PAGESIZE 0 TERM OFF

spool E:\abc\Test\File1_&MYPeriod.csv

select Account || ',' || Membername || ',' || GROUP || ',' || FUTURE1  from ACTUAL_V@UAT1_Test where Key=21 and period_name= '&MYPeriod' ;
spool off
exit
```

My queries :

1. When I run this , a file gets generated in location E:\abc\Test with a name File1_12-2012csv.Lst. I want a csv file .
   If i hard code the file name(replace &MYPeriod by test)  File1_Test.csv gets generated perfectly.Why the code is not able to create file with the name user has input..?
2. The output of this creates a csv file and retrieves the accounts from db but it prints two extra line at top. The new query and old query. How do I redefine my code, so that it gets remove automatically.

Appreciate your help guys.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: First I want the file name to File1_(what user enters the period).csv.. now its not doing that..

Comment: Second issue - if i fix my file name to File1_new.csv , then a csv file gets created with data , but this file has two extra lines :select Account || ',' || Membername || ',' || GROUP || ',' || FUTURE1  from ACTUAL_V@UAT1_Test where Key=21 and period_name= '&MYPeriod' ;
and 2nd line select Account || ',' || Membername || ',' || GROUP || ',' || FUTURE1  from ACTUAL_V@UAT1_Test where Key=21 and period_name= '&20-2012' ; . I dont want these two lines . How do i remove it..?

Comment: Is there a way I create a file with user input date at end : File1_12_2013.csv..something like this.?

Answer (score 2):

Substitution variables are [optionally terminated by a period](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref460) to separate them from any characters that follow. If you want to use one in the string as well, you have to add that termination explicitly:

```
spool E:\abc\Test\File1_&MYPeriod..csv
```

For the two extra lines issue, add [`set verify off`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699432); at the moment it is set to `on` (by default) so it shows you the old and new value of any substitution variables you use.

---

The only way I know to get the date into the file name is to put it into a substitution variable first:

```
set termout off
column x_run_dt new_value y_run_dt
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as x_run_dt from dual;
set termout on
spool E:\abc\Test\File1_&MYPeriod._&y_run_dt..csv
```

The `new_value` clause lets you create a substitution variable, `&y_run_dt` in this case, with a value from a queried column, `x_run_dt`. Wrapping the select that generates that value between `set termout` clauses hides it from the normal output, when run as a script.

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly.Also I would like to add current date and time the file was run. how do i add that..?sumthing like spool E:\abc\Test\File1_&MYPeriod.(+current date and time in system).csv..how do i do that.?